# Nested for loop has stopped working

Tags: c, user-defined-functions, nested-loops

This code here is is meant to grab random numbers (temperatures) and create a table with the corresponding hour in which the temperature was recorded. Here is an example of the output I am supposed to be receiving.

```
Temperature Conditions on October 9, 2015:
Time of Day    Temperature in degrees F
0               85
1               80
2               97
3               90
4               68
5               75
6               77
7               98
8               97
9               62
                etc...
Maximum Temperature for the day: <whatever> Degrees F
Minimum Temperature for the day: <whatever> Degrees F   
Average Temperature for the day: <whatever.whatever> Degrees F
```

My problem is that when I run the code a dialog box appears and says the program has stopped working and I don't quite know why.

All the help will be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int GetValue(int[]);

int main()  {
    int x, n, max = 0,min = 100, ArrayNumMax, ArrayNumMin, temperature[25];
    float sum;
    float average;
    int num[25];

    printf("Temperature Conditions on October 9, 2015:\nTime of Day \tTemperature in Degrees F\n");

for (x = 0; x <= 24; x++)    {

//if statements to get min and max

    temperature[x] = GetValue(temperature);
    if (temperature[x] > max)    {
        max = temperature[x];
        ArrayNumMax = x;
    }
    if (temperature[x] < min)    {
        min = temperature[x];
        ArrayNumMin = x;
    }

    printf("\t%d\t\t\t\t\t%d\n", x,temperature[x]);

}

//prints statements

printf("\nMidnight\t\t\t\t%d\n\nMaximum Temperature for the day: %d Degrees F at %d\nMinimum Temperature for the day: %d Degrees F at %d\n", temperature[12],max,ArrayNumMax, min, ArrayNumMin);

//adds up all temps

sum=0;

for (x=0;x<25;x++){

    sum=(sum+temperature[x]);
}

//prints and creates average

average=sum/25;

printf("Average Temperature for the day: %.2f Degrees F\n",average);

return 0;

}

//gets values and puts them into array

int GetValue(int value[])   {
    int x, temp[x];

    temp[x] = (rand()%(100-60+1))+60;

return temp[x];
}
```

Comment: In `GetValue()` you are using the automatic variable `int x` before it is initialized. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: You should also enable compiler warnings.  `GetValue` makes no sense at all.  It is passed a pointer to an array, but it completely ignores that argument.  Instead, it declares a local array, whose size is specified by an undefined variable, but then it uses it like a scalar.  It's hard to even guess at what the intent might have been.

Comment: the point of get value is to get a random number in which this case is the temperature.

Comment: @EOF how do I go about initializing it?

Answer (score 1):

**1**

What are you doing in your **GetValue** function?

---

```
int GetValue(int value[])   {
    int x, temp[x];  // create an array of undeclared amount x....

    temp[x] = (rand()%(100-60+1))+60; // at invalid memory set it to this value.

    return temp[x]; // then return this memory that I have no control over
}
```

Scrap this and go with this...

```
void GetValue(int value[], int x) {

    value[x] = (rand()%(100-60+1))+60;

}
```

Also above the main change

```
int GetValue(int[]);
```

to

```
void GetValue(int a[], int b);
```

Then in your main

```
//if statements to get min and max

GetValue(temperature, x);
if (temperature[x] > max)    {
```

Also you should look into preprocessor macros.
Read about them here. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_preprocessors.htm

such as #define

```
#define array_size 25
int array[array_size];
```

Then if you change your code and instead of 25 you need 50 then just change it once.

Comment: When i sub in your suggestion for the GetValue function i get an error

Comment: Did you change the deceleration above the main?

Answer (score 1):

Two error :

1. `x` in `GetValue` is not initialized so `temp[x]` has cross the border , so program encounter a segmentation fault.
2. When you define `temp[x]`, `x`'s value is undefine ,and `temp` exceed program's stack.

The right one maybe like this:

```
int GetValue(int value[])
{
    int x;
    x=1;
   int  temp[x];


    temp[x-1] = (int)((rand()%(100-60+1))+60);

    return temp[x-1];
}
```

The result shows that :

```
Temperature Conditions on October 9, 2015:
Time of Day     Temperature in Degrees F
        0                                       65
        1                                       96
        2                                       60
        3                                       83
        4                                       67
        5                                       79
        6                                       66
        7                                       92
        8                                       83
        9                                       77
        10                                      87
        11                                      66
        12                                      77
        13                                      66
        14                                      68
        15                                      82
        16                                      74
        17                                      79
        18                                      63
        19                                      73
        20                                      86
        21                                      70
        22                                      80
        23                                      81
        24                                      80

Midnight                                77

Maximum Temperature for the day: 96 Degrees F at 1
Minimum Temperature for the day: 60 Degrees F at 2
Average Temperature for the day: 76.00 Degrees F
```